# Magento Categories URL

Tags: url, categories, magento-1.6

cant seem to find anything related to this on Google. Though maybe I’m not searching the right keywords.

On Magento 1.6 I have a category I created. For example, "test". The seo url for that would have been:

mysite.com/test/

I then deleted the category(stupidly) and later recreated it. Now the category is called:

mysite.com/test-1/

Is there any way to reset the internal index or something so that I can once again have the url:

mysite.com/test/

Hope that makes sense and someone can help.

Thanks a lot for reading.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to write "test" in the "URL Key" field ?
This behavior has something to do with the "redirect 301" flag.

Bye
Giuseppe